# How to insert a variable in a query from .ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I thought this will be very simple but i think there is a bug when posting a variable from .ajax to a query. Is there any other way I ca get my result?

here is my jquery:

```
jQuery_1_4_2(document).ready(function() 
{
jQuery_1_4_2('.mainfolder').live("click",function() 
{
event.preventDefault();
var ID = jQuery_1_4_2(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'folder_id='+ ID;

if(ID=='')
{
alert("Serious Error Occured");
}
else
{
jQuery_1_4_2.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "display_folder.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
jQuery_1_4_2(".right_file").prepend(html);


}
 });
}


});

});
```

here is my display_folder.php

```
<?php
        $folder_id = $_POST['folder_id'];
        //echo $folder_id;
        $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_folder WHERE folder_id='$folder_id'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
            {
                echo $row['folder_name'] . "<br>";
                }

?>
```

Can anybody explain why this not work? i tried to echo $folder_id and it is working, but when you put it inside the query it is not working.

Note: This is not a dumb question where i forgot my connection of db. Thanks

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (_mysql_*_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (_mysqli_*_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: 1. Check `mysql_errno()`, `mysql_error()` for error messages from DBMS. 2. Check your database. 3. Check your database specified for connection.

Comment: I am trying to revive an old website that will use ajax, so if there is any other way not to recode the whole thing can somebody tell me what's the way?

Comment: Try trimming folder_id like `$folder_id=trim($_POST['folder_id'])`

Comment: not working. can you test it in your side, this is a simple small code. Just to clarify if the others also experiencing this problem then i think mysql functions are totally deprecated from jquery.

Comment: You should take note of @CORRUPT that he stated that mysql_* function are now deprecated. If you could execute your mysql_* function in your other sample files then above should work.

Comment: @NullVoid all my queries are working fine alone but when i posting a variable using jquery, it is not working anymore.

Comment: Actually `data:dataString` is working fine and I can get it in `$_POST` array. So it should also be working in your case.

Comment: @NullVoid i don't have any problems in getting the value of $_POST because i always get it. The problem is when I insert it in a query it is not working

Comment: I have updated my code. Check it. And I am getting proper values without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with both you and here I am providing (just for clean display) the same with some little formatting.

```
var dataString = 'folder_id=1';
        $.ajax({
            url: "folder.php",
            type:'post',
            async: false,
            data:dataString,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

and php part where I am getting `folder_id` properly.

```
<?php
    $postid = $_POST['folder_id'];
//echo $postid;
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test", $link);
$query = mysql_query("select * from post where id='$postid'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $row['text'] . "<br>"; //a, b etc in each row
}
?>
```

So it should work.

Comment: It is a `POST` request, so why?

Comment: Even with a `GET` request using the `$.ajax` helper placing data into the `data` property is suffice, this will not help.

Comment: this is working yes. I used this same code. I write "test" in folder.php and the alert box prompted "test". This is working. The problem is when you test a query in the folder.php, for example "SELECT * FROM test". There should be output but it only display blank.

Comment: I think I am having a problem with my computer. If this code works fine then the problem is in my side. I actually copy and paste this code and create a test database with text field in it and i'm not getting any in the alert box. Thanks for testing it for me.

Comment: Actually above should also work in you machine too. `id` and `text` fields needed to check above one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php code

```
<?php
    $folder_id = addslashes($_POST['folder_id']);
    //echo $folder_id;
    $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_folder WHERE folder_id='$folder_id'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            echo $row['folder_name'] . "<br>";
            }

 ?>
```